# focus on dropdownlist after pressing enter using javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i keep focus on dropdownlist after pressing enter using javascript.I have written code for the same,but the focus is on textbox and later on dropdownlist.But i want the focus first on dropdownlist and later on textbox.Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong.Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="msdropdown/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('input:text:first').focus();
 var $inp = $('.cls');
 var n = $inp.length;
 $inp.bind('keydown', function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if (key == 13) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
 if(nxtIdx < n)
 $(".cls:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();
 else {
 $(".cls:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").blur();
  }
  }
  });
  });
  </script>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"   
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="STATUS" DataValueField="STATUS" 
Width="70px" CssClass="cls">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="STATUS" DataValueField="STATUS" 
Width="70px" CssClass="cls">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="STATUS" DataValueField="STATUS" 
Width="70px" CssClass="cls">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="70px" 
CssClass="cls"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
Width="70px" CssClass="cls"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="70px" 
CssClass="cls"></asp:TextBox>
```